# html is not catching file

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this html `<script src="js/token.js"></script>` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/token.css">` is not taking the file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>FIY - Reset Password</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/form.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/password.css">
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="loader">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div class="alert-box">
    <img src="/img/cross.png" class="alert-img" />
    <p class="alert-msg">Error message</p>
  </div>

  <h1 id="heading">Reset Password for <span id="email-span"></span></h1>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left-img">
      <img src="/img/reset-password.png" />
    </div>
    <form class="right" method="POST">
      <h1>Reset Password</h1>
      <div>
        <input type="password" autocomplete="off" required="required" id="password" />
        <span>New Password</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="password" autocomplete="off" required="required" id="password2" />
        <span>Confirm Password</span>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Reset Password" id="btn">
    <form>
  </div>

  <script src="js/token.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Even another HTML is catching the file.
File structure link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t6NZ671ixzrbb9Cczodt8yaAzOPlm19R/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The path is wrong I guess. Please show file structure

Comment: What do you mean by "taking the file" or "catching the file"? Is this a JS problem, an HTML problem, or a CSS problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase this is a HTML problem

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Path is right because it is working in other HTML files

Comment: Are other html files in the same folder?

Comment: Yes all files are in same folder

Comment: open your browser developer console and look for errors. cntrl+shift+i. Can the browser find the files?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I give the file structure link

Comment: Please share all clarification in text form. Don't link to external ressources to clarify your problem, as such links might become invalid

Comment: You could at least add these links directly, not in a zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the name of the HTML and CSS file? I might be wrong but unless you put a `js/` and a `css/` on your file names you should put their regular names. For the CSS it would be `token.css` and for your Javascript it would be `token.js`.